# Dataflow errors - "500 Internal Server Error" & "503 Service Unavailable"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We've started getting 500 & 503 errors in our Pipelines when running them this morning. Looks like it cannot get the job status once again.

```
46142 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob  - There were problems getting current job status: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
  "status" : "INTERNAL"
}

1399601 [main] WARN  com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineJob  - There were problems getting current job status: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "The service is currently unavailable.",
  "status" : "UNAVAILABLE"
}
```

What's the problem?

Job id: 2015-05-19_17_41_46-7486669477281046678

Comment: Polley, I'm trying to reproduce the issue on my end (unsuccessfully). Can you share more details with me?

Comment: We have identified a transient issue now, actively working on resolving it. Stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks. One repro on my end suggests the job  submission succeeds and the job runs as expected, but the client is struggling with retrieving status. You should see the job in the dev console as running (or completed), which I believe is the experience you are describing.

Comment: that is correct. Error is client side.

Comment: Alright! The issue should be resolved now. Thanks polleyg!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a client-side only issue that was not affecting job submission, due to a transient error. Should not be occurring anymore.